# How can I get instances of different tabs such that I can store variables / perform operations specific to respective tabs

Tags: javascript, gwt, firefox-addon

Note: I am using GWT to build a firefox extension

Say I have a class which operates on the different TABs of the browser:

```java
class TabRoutine{
  Element tab;
  static int tabData;

  public TabRoutine(Element tab){
    this.tab=tab;
  }

  public void tabMethod(){
    //Operation on tab
  }      
}
```

For each tab I must create an instance of this class which I want to destroy once the tab closes. Therefore each tab has an int tabData related to it. Here is how I approached it:

I have the document element pertaining to each tab available with me (I also have the window object if that helps). Therefore, I decided to use

```javascript
gBrowser.getBrowserForDocument(doc);
```

My question is does this Browser element I get unique for tabs? What I imply is that say I have 2 tabs with documents doc1 and doc2. If I map these Browser elements to objects of TabRoutine, would each individual tab always return the same (and correct) browser so that i can find the object related to it?

Please tell if some aspect of the question is unclear and I'll elaborate. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each `<browser>` element is associated with a particular tab. It is not bound to a particular content document however - a different site can be loaded into the same tab. You probably want to go through the [`gBrowser.browsers` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#p-browsers) when your extension starts. Then you would listen to [`TabOpen` and `TabClose` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Notification_when_a_tab_is_added_or_removed) to get notified whenever a tab is opened or closed (use [`gBrowser.getBrowserForTab` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#m-getBrowserForTab) to get the `<browser>` element that these events are associated with).